# Accessing existing voice notes from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk

I want my current iPhone App to access the iPhone for existing voice notes.

Two questions on that:

1. Where by default the voice notes on iPhone gets stored.
2. Do I have access to Audio Recorder (Voice Momos) App from my iPhone App.
3. Do I have access to those voice note from my iPhone App. (If no, then is there any reference which provides proof for the same, that I don't have that access?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not provide any API for voice notes, so there is no way to access them.

You want prove that you can't access them, which I can't not give. But since the developers documentation does not provide API for voice memos you should accept that is is not allowed by apple.