# How to save your audio files to Voice Memo

Tags: ios, swift, audio, persistence

I have a compatible m4a file with URL and access to NSData of the audio file itself.  How do I save the file to Voice Memo?

For example, I can save an image via UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() or UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum() for videos.

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't any API access, so you can't. - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256549/accessing-existing-voice-notes-from-iphone-app

Comment: I was afraid of that... no wonder I couldn't find anything in the docs...  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that this is **NOT possible**. Apple does not provide APIs that can help you with doing this.